# neo4j spatial findGeometriesWithinDistance REST

Tags: rest, neo4j, py2neo, neo4j-spatial

Using neo4j 1.9 and neo4j spatial for 1.9.
Trying to get `findGeometriesWithinDistance` REST call working.

I can confirm that the install has worked and that the function exists BUT, using the http console I get a `"Node 0 does not exist"` error. The REST request I make is exactly [as in the docs](http://neo4j.github.io/spatial/#spatial-server-plugin) but instead of returning nodes I get this error.

What is going on that requires node 0 to exist and hence causes the error?

For info, the REST `findGeometriesInBBox` works fine.

**On Further Investigation...**

Using py2neo to interact with the DB. In particular, we make use of the `GregorianCalendar` functionality ([see here)](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/calendar/). When removed from our logic the process of `findGeometriesWithinDistance` works fine.

Looking into it further, there are comments in the py2neo code that say `#retain a handle to the root node` (see the first code example [here](http://blog.nigelsmall.com/2012/09/modelling-dates-in-neo4j.html)).

Does this "handle" do something with the node of index 0 so we can't use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you accidentally clean out your database?

I.e. remove node 0, which was the reference node that neo4j-spatial connected its root elements to (in 1.9)?

Comment: Do you have that DB somewhere to test it?

Comment: So...nop, we didn't clean out the DB and quite sure non of our logic deletes the 0 index node. BUT, I have modified the question with further info, it might be a py2neo GregorianCalendar problem

Comment: Yep...after getting through some more of the logic there it was graph_db.clear().